# Color all objects within polar grid

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs5, pathfinder

First off, I am new to illustrator so may be going at this the wrong way.

I have a design that involves multiple paths that form a web like structure in a circle. I would like to have the color of the web into three equal parts and color them.

I have divided the circle up using the polar grid tool. I would like to create a color mask from this for all layers below but I don't seem to be able to do that. Alternatively, I though i could turn the polar grid into a selection and then just color all the paths below using that.

The problem is that some of the web cross over the paths created by the polar grid so they would have to be half one color and half another.

I hope I have explained myself okay.

Comment: Illustrator is *not* Photoshop. The Polar Grid tool creates vector *objects*. While you may be able to use those objects in conjunction with other operations, such as Pathfinder, there's customarily no direct way to interact with existing objects. I think you'll need to explain much further about what you are trying to accomplish with some sample screenshots, and forget about the Polar Grid tool. It may be appropriate but if you've already got things drawn, it may not be.

Comment: Possibly Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22529/illustrator-how-to-colour-segments-of-a-circle-with-different-colours/22537#22537  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51295/segment-circle-into-layers  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27964/how-do-i-divide-a-circle-into-equal-parts-like-a-pie-chart-with-adobe-illustrato